# AWS amplify working on the backend as a team

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am interested in the AWS Amplify technology, but what I don't understand is how to enable other developers to collaborate on the backend.  I understand with the frontend you can just hook it up to github and it works fine and I've had friends make changes.  How do you work on the backend as a team?  Thanks!

Comment: You can create multiple backedn environments, i.e: user1-dev-mybackend, user2-dev-my-backend, etc, etc, and you pull/push changes from one to another, like git branches

Comment: Thanks @danielfranca!